# AnyLogic: How to show Time-average number of components in the queue of the operation in Graph?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I calculate the number of components in the queue. As you can see in the image below,
[image]

1. **What I want to do is show the number of components in the queue with time.**
2. **How can I calculate the time-average number of components in the whole system?**

Kindly let me know how I can do that.
Thank you.

**Logic of System:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use a time-plot element from the Analysis palette. Let's say you want to update the graph every 10 min, then you fill it this way for the queue:

[image]

Then, for the number of agents in the system as a whole, you can use the same approach, but change the value to:

```
source.count() - sink.count() - scrapped.count();
```